# Is there efficient way of finding last number in following sequence

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

"Imagine the sequence lying on a circle. Take every second number in the sequence. Continue the process until you finish"

Is there efficient way of finding last number in following sequence :

we have numbers $1,2,...n$, we delete $2,4,...,$ and start it again so

$n=2$ gives $2$

$n=10$ gives $5$, because : $2,4,6,8,10,3,7,1,9,5$

$n=25$ gives $19 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,1,5,9,13,17,21,25,7,15,23,11,3,19$

is there any short way to for calculationg last number for given $n$ ? Ive some clues when I look at $n=2^k$

edition : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JosephusProblem.html
really good article

and here is solution :

http://oeis.org/A032434

answer is : (1+2*n-pow(2,1+floor(log2(n)))

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what exactly the algorithm does? It is not clear to me.

Comment: Imagine the sequence lying on a circle. Start from 2, Take every second number in the sequence and delete them at each step. Continue the process until you finish.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem

Comment: I feel kind of bad for saying "delete them at each step" after reading the anecdote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wikipedia provides an explicit solution for the **Josephus problem** (as this is called) for every 2nd elimination: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem).

There is also a more general discussion on eliminating with less frequency....

Comment: And the Josephus problem figures prominently in Concrete Mathematics by Graham, Knuth, Patashnik.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Yes, that's where I remembered the name from.